# Сравниние и комбинирование ассоциативных массивов

Tags: php, массивы, сравнение

Есть два массива дат за последние 7 дней:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-04-27
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-04-28
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-04-29
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-04-30
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-05-01
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-05-02
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-05-03
    )
```

)

И есть массив, полученный результатом выборки из БД(сумма заказов по каждому дню за последнюю неделю):

```
 Array

 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-04-28
        [cost] => 2810
    )
```

)

Нужно эти два массива объеденить таким образом чтобы получилось вот так:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-04-27
        [cost] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-04-28
        [cost] => 2810
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-04-29
        [cost] => 0
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-04-30
        [cost] => 0
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-05-01
        [cost] => 0
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-05-02
        [cost] => 0
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [days] => 2018-05-03
        [cost] => 0
    )
```

)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант сделать перебор через `foreach`:

```html
$data = array(
    array('dayz' => '2018-04-27'),
    array('dayz' => '2018-04-28'),
    array('dayz' => '2018-04-29'),
    array('dayz' => '2018-04-30')
);

$data_in_db = array(
    array('dayz' => '2018-04-27', 'cost' => 0),
    array('dayz' => '2018-04-28', 'cost' => 3),
    array('dayz' => '2018-04-29', 'cost' => 2),
);

$new_data = array();
foreach ($data_in_db as $db_row) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['dayz'] == $db_row['dayz']) {
            $new_data[] = array(
                'dayz' => $db_row['dayz'],
                'cost' => $db_row['cost']
            );
            continue;
        }
        if ($key == (count($data_in_db) - 1)) {
            $new_data[] = array(
                'dayz' => $db_row['dayz'],
                'cost' => 0
            );
        }
    }
}
print_r($new_data);
```

Comment: Если например с базы стянул одну дату, ваш пример возвращает вот такое массив
      Array ( [0] => 
Array ( 
[days] => 2018-04-29 
[cost] => 0 )
 [1] => Array ( 
[days] => 2018-04-29
 [cost] => 2 
)
 )